# How to activate web application and site collection level feature via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

We have deployed a wsp using:

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath $path
install-spsolution -Identity $solution  -GACDeployment -Force
```

This wsp has 2 features, one scoped at application level (FeatureA) and one scoped at site collection level (FeatureB). Both can be seen and activated/deactivated from the respective UI's.

I would like to know how to activate them via powershell.

I tried:

```
Enable-SPFeature -identity "FeatureB" -confirm:$false -url $oUrl
```

Gives error as:

> Enable-spfeature : The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not
>   found in a Site level defined by the Url `http://dewswift:7676/`. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Enable-spfeature -identity "FeatureB" -confirm:$f ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...etEnableFeature:SPCmdletEnableFeature)
>   [Enable-SPFeature], SPCmdletException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletEnableFeature

Comment: are you working with sharepoint online?

Comment: no the in house intranet, not sharepoint online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check if the feature is installed using `Scope` and then try to activate it like:

```
$Feature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If ($Feature.Scope -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureScope]::WebApplication)
{
    $Feature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -WebApplication $SiteUrl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Enable-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Url $SiteUrl  -Confirm:$false 
}
ElseIf ($Feature.Scope -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureScope]::Site)
{
    $Feature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Site $SiteUrl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Enable-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Url $SiteUrl  -Confirm:$false 
}
```

Comment: How to get FeatureID

Comment: It is present in Feature manifest file.

Comment: within the IF loop why have you used $Feature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -WebApplication $SiteUrl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue?

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me when I try to enable a feature from a SharePoint server that does not have the SharePoint service running: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application . The web sites are not hosted on IIS on these servers and the layouts folder do not have the features deployed to them! A common practice is to turn off the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application on a dedicate APP/Central admin server. But then you cannot enable features.