# Can't see feature on my webApplication

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, feature, timer-jobs, feature-activation

I did a solution for a `SPJobDefinition`. Feature scope is `WebApplication` as required.
I have event **FeatureActivated** but when i deploy solution. When i go to CA -> Manage WebApplication -> select one and Manage Feature i don't see it.

My job is really base like this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798313.aspx

What could be the mistake?

Comment: can you see the solution deployed to farm? check from central admin > system settings> manage farm solutions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try classic RETRACT -> DELETE -> ADD -> INSTALL WSP. 
   In most cases it will solve the issue.

   Or
2. just change the SCOPE to SPSITE & ensure that the Job Lock type for your timer is Against Content DB & then Activate it in the SPSITE level.

   Or
3. One more thought: Double Click the feature in Visual studio & then hit F4 to bring up Properties dialog. There ensure that the feature is not hidden.

   Or
4. Why not activate it using powershell using the feature ID
   use the reference [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95429/how-to-activate-web-application-and-site-collection-level-feature-via-powershell)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I finally choose your 4th solution and activate it by ps